# Find formula of Harmonic Function

Tags: complex-analysis

I need help with this problem:
Let $0\leq a<b<2\pi, \Delta=B(0,1)$ and let $f$ be the function on the unit circle
    $\{|z|=1\}$ defined by
    [
    f(e^{i\theta}) = \begin{cases}
 1 & a\leq \theta\leq b \\
 0 & 0\leq \theta<a \text{ or } b<\theta<2\pi.
 \end{cases}
    ]
         Find a formula for the harmonic function $u
 :\thinspace \Delta \to \R$ that limits to $f$ on the unit circle.

This is the first time I see Poisson Integral formula, I don't know how to solve it. Here is what I have as a start:

Using the polar coordinates of Poisson's formula, we have
    [\begin{aligned}
 U(re^{i\varphi})=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{a}^{b}\frac{1-r^2}{1-2r\cos(\theta-\varphi)+r^2}d\theta\\
 \end{aligned}]But, how to solve such integral? Thanks!